# Potential Resource Leak Warning

Tags: java

Eclipse complains that the response.body() could be a potential resource leak. Will there actually be a leak here? The documentation says that response.body().string() will close the resource.

*Just to be clear, i understand **how** (try-with-resources) to resolve the warning. I'm just wondering in what case will the resource actually be leaked here? If it's not null, it should get automatically closed. If it is null, well... then there is nothing to close... ?*

Response is: **okhttp3.Response**

```
try {
    if (response.body() != null) {
        String respBody = response.body().string();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new ApiException(e);
}
```

As per one of the answers, i attempted to do the following and got the same warning:

```
try {
    ResponseBody body = response.body()
    if (body != null) {
        String respBody = body.string();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new ApiException(e);
}
```

Comment: What is `response`?

Comment: What object is `response`? Does it implement `AutoCloseable`?

Comment: Could you include the types of the variables in this example

Comment: you need to post some context so people can understand what is `response` and, more important, you can look into the source code and see what it is doing.

Comment: What happens if you do `resp = response.body(); if(resp != null) { respBody = resp.string(); }`?

Comment: @CodeMonkey sorry it is okhttp3.Response

Comment: @Nikolas yes: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html

Comment: What IDE do you use, Eclipse?

Comment: @Nikolas yes, Eclipse

Comment: @BigBug: There might be an IDE problem displaying warning incorrectly.

Comment: @Nikolas i see, okay - thought I was missing something. Thank-you!

Comment: @Nikolas Can you post this as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @BigBug: I am not sure this is a real answer to your problem. Just a guess, that's why I used a word `"might"`.

Comment: I have added an answer that should be suitable to what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check `response.body() != null`, I believe that you are creating a new stream of `ResponseBody`, which is left open, even after you line `String respBody = response.body().string()`. Because you leave this stream open, it is giving you the warning of a potential resource leak.

Pinkie Swirl's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952517/2112501) should fix your problem, using the try-with-resource method.

As for your edit to show the second method you tried, I would surmise that it is throwing the warning because Eclipse is not capable of seeing that `.string()` is closing the stream of the object `ResponseBody body`. However, I could also say that it might be warning because it may still be creating a stream, and if `body` is null, then it is never closed, because `.string()` is never called.

There is no harm in calling `.close()` explicitly after you are done with the object. It is probably best practice to do so, anyway since you have conditional steps. Auto closing a stream in `.string()` is weird, but you have no control over that.

Answer (score 2):

The [javadoc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html) shows how to use it properly:

```
try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
    ... // Use the response.
}
```

This will automatically add a finally clause to it. This properly handles exceptions during reading **and** closing the stream.

**EDIT 2**

After doing some more research it seems it closes the resource properly (no leak).

Eclipse reports a warning since it does not check if the `string()` method closes the resource properly. In fact eclipse does not follow any methods to check for this warning (so you would get this warning if you wrote your own close method). This means it reports a false positive in this case.

It probably does so because it is quite difficult/impossible to check for all implementations that properly close a resource in a timely manner.

However it is still good practice to use try with resource, because then you simply need not to worry how the underlying code handles stuff.

Comment: I understand how to fix the warning. The question was, why is it a warning in the first place - i don't actually see where a leak could occur in the code i have above. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: But he is not closing the stream on response.body(), where he is getting the warning.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding OP which would lead to my misunderstanding about this, but your edit 2 still does not seem to answer the question. On the line that he calls `reponse.body()` he is getting the warning, but when he does `response.body().string()` the warning does not appear. I agree with you that he should use a try-with-resource, which should solve his problem. But the question asks why he would get the warning on `response.body()` when not using try-with-resources.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl CodeMonkey is correct. I was looking for the "why" not how to fix the problem. Also, as pointed out by CodeMonkey, the warning appears on response.body() not body.string()...

Comment: Yeah exactly there it should appear, because that is a resource. And that's what  I tried to say

Comment: Eclipse does not check if a method closes a stream -> warning on the resource. Why should it warn on an arbitrary method it does not check? But you got your answer, so everything is fine?